# Clang and Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, clang

I try to make AST file for Linux kernel 2.6.37 code with clang 8.0.0.
I run following in kernel root directory

```
clang -emit-ast init/main.c -o astfile -std=c11 -Iinclude -Iarch/x86/include
```

and get errors

```
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/init/main.c:12:
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/types.h:13:2: warning: "Attempt to use kernel
      headers from user space, see http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHeaders" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Attempt to use kernel headers from user space, see http://kernelnewbies...
 ^
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/init/main.c:13:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/module.h:9:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/list.h:7:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/prefetch.h:14:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:15:
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:12:8: error: unknown type
      name '__always_inline'
static __always_inline struct task_struct *get_current(void)
       ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:12:24: error: expected
      identifier or '('
static __always_inline struct task_struct *get_current(void)
                       ^
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/init/main.c:13:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/module.h:9:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/list.h:7:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/prefetch.h:14:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:17:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/system.h:7:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/cmpxchg.h:4:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/cmpxchg_64.h:4:
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:47:2: error: unknown
      type name 'u8'
        u8 *instr;              /* original instruction */
        ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:48:2: error: unknown
      type name 'u8'
        u8 *replacement;
        ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:49:2: error: unknown
      type name 'u16'
        u16 cpuid;              /* cpuid bit set for replacement */
        ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:50:2: error: unknown
      type name 'u8'
        u8  instrlen;           /* length of original instruction */
        ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:51:2: error: unknown
      type name 'u8'
        u8  replacementlen;     /* length of new instruction, <= instrlen */
        ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:164:62: error: unknown
      type name 'size_t'
extern void *text_poke_early(void *addr, const void *opcode, size_t len);
                                                             ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:183:56: error: unknown
      type name 'size_t'
extern void *text_poke(void *addr, const void *opcode, size_t len);
                                                       ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:184:60: error: unknown
      type name 'size_t'
extern void *text_poke_smp(void *addr, const void *opcode, size_t len);
                                                           ^
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/init/main.c:13:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/module.h:9:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/list.h:7:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/prefetch.h:14:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:17:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/system.h:7:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/cmpxchg.h:4:
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/cmpxchg_64.h:6:39: error: unknown type
      name 'u64'
static inline void set_64bit(volatile u64 *ptr, u64 val)
                                      ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/cmpxchg_64.h:6:49: error: unknown type
      name 'u64'
static inline void set_64bit(volatile u64 *ptr, u64 val)
                                                ^
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/init/main.c:13:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/module.h:9:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/list.h:7:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/prefetch.h:14:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:17:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/system.h:11:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/irqflags.h:15:
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:20:2: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'asm'
        asm volatile("# __raw_save_flags\n\t"
        ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:31:2: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'asm'
        asm volatile("push %0 ; popf"
        ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:39:2: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'asm'
        asm volatile("cli": : :"memory");
        ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:44:2: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'asm'
        asm volatile("sti": : :"memory");
        ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:49:2: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'asm'
        asm volatile("sti; hlt": : :"memory");
        ^
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:54:2: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'asm'
        asm volatile("hlt": : :"memory");
        ^
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/init/main.c:13:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/module.h:9:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/list.h:7:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/include/linux/prefetch.h:14:
In file included from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:17:
/mnt/lfs/sources/linux-2.6.37/arch/x86/include/asm/system.h:335:2: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'asm'
        asm volatile("clflush %0" : "+m" (*(volatile char __force *)__p));
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
1 warning and 20 errors generated.
```

Please help, I have tried to google about this errors, but found nothing appropriate. I have added kernel header from kernel source directory with `-I` flag, because compiler could not find them on my system ArchLinux 5.0.10-arch1-1-ARCH.

Comment: This is kernel. This is way more complicated then running a simple command. Inspect the headers by hand, see what's wrong, inspect `types.h:13:2` and `see http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHeaders`. I believe you would need to add all the `#define CONFIG_` your kernel should be configured with.

Comment: Thanks for replay. `types.h:13:2` is just worning message with link to `http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHeaders`. I found nothing new there. About `#define CONFIG_`, do you mean config enties in `.config` file which is used during kernel compilation?

Comment: How is [that](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.36/source/include/linux/types.h#L6) nothing? It's clear you have to `-D__KERNEL__` or `-D__EXPORTED_HEADERS__` for that error to go away. Please start with a good C book. And yea - by that I mean all the macros defined inside `.config` file, but not only, including these needed for kernel compilation, ex. like `__KERNEL__`. Below are also typedefs for `__u8` types and such.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry, It is my fault, I haven't read that is below in `types.h`. After defining macros `asm` error stayed alone. I have already read `Kernighan and Ritchie C programming`.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk, your advice is really smart. I find which macro I should add in header files and gradually fix errors. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've done this with help of [Kamil Cuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamil-cuk). I've used my `.config` file which have been generated for compilation during kernel configuration. I've opened it in Vim, removed `#`-lines and `=y`, added `#define` in the beginning of each line and saved as `config.h` in kernel root directory.

```
clang -emit-ast init/main.c -o astfile -I include -I arch/x86/include -D __EXPORTED_HEADERS__ -D __KERNEL__ -include config.h
```